# How do I temporariliy change the IP of my computer to connect directly to a NAS?

Tags: ip, ubuntu-16.04, nas

I have a Synology NAS which I wish to connect directly to my computer through the ethernet cable.

I understand so far that I need to set my computer IP address to the range of the IP of the NAS, which should be set by default by the DHCP server.

How do I know which is the IP address given to the NAS by the DHCP (192.164.0.1/254) ?   And then knowing that, how do I set the IP of my computer to that range, temporarily as not to mess up with the configurations in a long term?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

What I have tried so far:

1. Changed my IPv4 Address from DHCP to Manual, and assigned 192.168.0.1
2. Disconnected ethernet cable from the internet port and connected it to the NAS
3. Restarted the Wired connection (Connected, 1000MB/s)
4. Checked for connected devices with nmap and zenmap.
5. only one device was found, 192.168.0.1 (myself)...

   Redid the same using IP 192.168.0.2

Comment: Does the NAS device have more than one Ethernet port? If not, how will it talk to a DHCP server and your computer at the same time?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are right, it can't, you are helping already. How does the ip address assignment work in this case?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz However, the NAS was connected to the internet before, and had a static IP address, reachable through the network.

Comment: You could configure the NAS device to be a DHCP server. You could configure the PC to be a DHCP server. You could configure both devices to have a static IP address. Those are your choices.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that is a good summary. I am a the third one. The NAS has a static IP address, but on connection it is not detected.

Comment: You need to configure a static IP address in the NAS device as well, say 192.168.0.10 or something like that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so my confusion arises because of the following two alternative theories: I have been told that when I unplug the NAS from the network, its IP address goes back to a factory default one. Alternatively, I can set a static IP of my choice, which won't be reseted after unpluging the NAS from the network. Because I am failing to connect to the NAS directly, it is either because the NAS IP resets to an unknown default, or because the static IP I am setting is not useful (it was outside of the 192.168.0 network)

Comment: That all sounds correct. So configure an appropriate static IP address in the NAS.